# Add style for every buttons in ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have over 20 buttons in my XCode project, and i want to add border to every of them. is it possible to like select all the UIButtons in the storyboard and then perform codes on them?

```
// For example
buttons.borderColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor];
buttons.cornerRadius = 8;
buttons.borderWidth = 1;
```

Comment: you may want to subset the `UIButton` and set the styles in that instance overriding the `–drawRect:` method, then change the _Custom class_ in _IB_ from `UIButton` to yours. it can be the fastest and cleanest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the UIAppearance protocol.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html

Comment: ... and read up on *appearance proxies* generally. This is exactly what they're for.